# How to customise the screen size in Android Using getWindowManager()

Tags: android, screen

I have an isue on screen size. As of now I displayed an image in an window screen. I used below code to get the screen size for all devices.

gridSize will be 3*3 or 4*4

```
public  void createGameBoard(short gridSize) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    TableLayout tableLayout;
    tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout1);    
    tableLayout.removeAllViews();

    board = GameBoard.createGameBoard(this, 
            bitmap, 
            tableLayout,
            (int) (metrics.widthPixels * metrics.density),
            (int) (metrics.heightPixels * metrics.density),
            gridSize);

}
```

Now I want the above method to be customize. that, I want to some gap at top and bottom of this screen to place some content.  I don't want default window size. I want to change with some values for `widthPixels` and `heightPixels` to get a space at the top and bottom of this screen.

Can any one help me out?

Thanks 
Ram

Answer (score 0):

if  you can set your board position then below code help you.

here gapSize is top and bottom gap.

```
    int gapSize = 10; // you can set any value
    int width = (int) (metrics.widthPixels * metrics.density);// your board width
    int height = (int) (metrics.heightPixels * metrics.density) - (2 * gapSize);// your board height
    int startX = 0, startY = gapSize;


   board = GameBoard.createGameBoard(startX,startY,this, 
        bitmap, 
        tableLayout,
        width , height , gridSize);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this code and I got the space at the bottom  not at the top. I tried to get space at the top,  I did't get . Let me now the reason and code to get space at the top.